# How to get fallthrough/logical or in dsp:switch tags

Tags: java, html, jsp, jakarta-ee, atg

I'm using the ATG (formerly known as Dynamo) J2EE tag library. There are about 4 cases in which I want a fairly large amount of markup to show up, but in every other case, different markup should show up.  As I have been doing it, I've given each case it's own `dsp:oparam`, like this:

```
<dsp:droplet name="Switch">  
<dsp:param name="value" param="thing.ReturnCode"/>
  <dsp:oparam name="THING001">
    <!-- Do stuff here -->
  </dsp:oparam>
  <dsp:oparam name="THING002">
    <!-- Do the same stuff as above here -->
  </dsp:oparam>
  <dsp:oparam name="default">
    <!-- Do different stuff here -->
  </dsp:oparam>
</dsp:droplet>
```

This seems inefficient though, as it requires me to make changes to each of those blocks if I want a change.  Is there a way to get fall through, so that I can have a block which works for both THING001 and THING002?

Comment: if you want something common to both block then you can have that code out of the switch. its simple. please explain if you have some other requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be able to do something like this

```
<dsp:getvalueof var="returnCode" param="thing.ReturnCode" />
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${returnCode == 'thing1' or returnCode == 'thing2'}">
       DO STUFF
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        DO STUFF
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```